# selecting multiple checkboxes in qt

Tags: qt

I have a problem performing multiple check operations. Basically what i do is I will click on mark several action to call markSeveral() and then from there i call clicked() signal of list to call setcheckBoxes() and then set the checkboxes. now the provlem is dis happens perfectly qt first time, but when i do it for second time the setcheckboxes() slot is called twice hence d checkboxes are not set. Again for third attempt the setcheckboxes() slot is called thrice but d checkboxes do get set.

Why is the slot called so many times when i make a call to it only once?

please tell me what I am doin wrong

Thanks in advance. here is the piece of my code:

```
void Browser::markSeveral()
{
    itemClicked=true;
    multiSelect=true;
    MarkClicked=true;
    MarkMenuClicked=true;

    connect(list,SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)),this,SLOT(setCheckBoxes(QModelIndex)));
}

void Browser::setCheckBoxes(QModelIndex index)
{

    if(MarkClicked ==true && model->data(index,Qt::CheckStateRole) == Qt::Unchecked)
    {        
        model->setData(index,Qt::Checked,Qt::CheckStateRole);
        indexList.append(index);
    }
    else
    {
        if(MarkClicked ==true && model->data(index,Qt::CheckStateRole) == Qt::Checked)
        {
            model->setData(index,Qt::Unchecked,Qt::CheckStateRole);
            indexList.removeOne(index);
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you connect a signal to a slot n times, emitting the signal once will call the slot n times. If you call markSeveral() multiple times, you have multiple connections.

You should do the connect() call only once, usually in the ctor of Browser.
Or ensure that there is only one connection, by using Qt::UniqueConnection:

```
connect( list,SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)),this,SLOT(setCheckBoxes(QModelIndex)), Qt::UniqueConnection );
```

This ensures that there is exactly one connection.
The former option (calling connect() once when setting up the widget) is to be preferred though.

Comment: or pass `Qt::UniqueConnection` as the 5th parameter to `connect()`

Comment: mmutz: Right, forgot about that relatively new (well, not that new...) option.